# Create a special li-menu in fluid with a flexform table array

Tags: typo3, fluid

in a flexform configuration i have a select-field "categoryTags"

```
<config>
  <type>select</type>
  <foreign_table>sys_category</foreign_table>
  <minitems>0</minitems>
  <maxitems>10</maxitems>
  <multiple>1</multiple>
  <dce_load_schema>1</dce_load_schema>
</config>
```

in fluid-template i get the followig array from it as example:

```
array(3 items)
0 => array(29 items)
    uid => '77' (2 chars)
    title => 'Category1' (18 chars)
    ...
1 => array(29 items)
    uid => '78' (2 chars)
    title => 'Category2' (18 chars)
    ...
2 => array(29 items)
    uid => '79' (2 chars)
    title => 'Category3' (18 chars)
    ...
```

now i want to get a list of categories in a li-menu. but all category title´s should be displayed (not only the selected - i will do this manually) and if the category is selected in the flexform, a class should be changed or added.

the result should be:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="selected">Category1</li>
  <li class="">Category2</li>
  <li class="">Category3</li>
</ul>
```

eg. this shows only the selected one´s (not all):

```
<f:for each="{field.categoryTags}" as="tags">
  <li>{tags.title} <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</f:for>
```

and this of course won´t work in the loop:

```
<f:for each="{field.categoryTags}" as="tags">
  <li class="{f:if(condition: '{tags.uid} == 77', then: 'selected')}">Category1</li>
  <li class="{f:if(condition: '{tags.uid} == 78', then: 'selected')}">Category2</li>
  <li class="{f:if(condition: '{tags.uid} == 79', then: 'selected')}">Category3</li>
</f:for>
```

is there a possibility in fluid?

Comment: category ID 77,78,79 is it static or will you get from somewhere else means from controller?

Comment: in this case the category IDs are static, they come from a content element, created with extension dynamic content elements (dce) and will not chance.

Comment: either you can use ifelse ifelse condition of fluid or create your own custom viewhelper and you have PHP condition with in_array($tagUid,array(77,78,79)) http://blog.typo3servers.info/show/typo3-extbase-create-a-custom-viewhelper/